# Does the c++ friend keyword mean more then access to private?

Tags: c++, friend-function

I wrote simple class and define one copy constructor.
Then add friend equal comparison operator and compare `int` with `Int`

```
template <class T>
class Int {
public:
    T value;
    Int(const T& value_) : value(value_) {
        ;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const Int<T>& f, const Int<T>& s) {
        return f.value == s.value;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a;
    Int<int> x(a);
    x == a;
}
```

Compiled successfully.

If I turn the `friend bool operator==(const Int<T>& f, const Int<T>& s);` into a non-friend template. I get a compiler error:

> ```
> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'int' and 'Int<int>'
> ```

```
template <class T>
class Int {
public:
    T value;
    Int(const T& value_) : value(value_) {
        ;
    }
};

template <class T>
bool operator==(const Int<T>& f, const Int<T>& s) {
    return f.value == s.value;
}

int main() {
    int a;
    Int<int> x(a);
    x == a;
}
```

Does it mean that friend functions allow specific conversions?

`5 == x` works too.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error you get. See [ask].

Comment: What do you mean _more_? There's nothing _more_ beyond `private` access level.

Comment: Yes, if I mark constructor as`explicit` I get compiler error in both variants.
I want to know why compiler sense this two examples differently

Comment: "Compiled successfully". [That's not quite enough](https://ideone.com/paQ0ZN).

Answer (score 1):

> Does the c++ friend keyword mean more then access to private?

Depending on context, it can have more implications, yes. For instance, a `friend` function defined inline, with no other declaration, can only be found by argument dependent lookup, even though it's a member of the enclosing namespace:

```
namespace foo {
    struct bar {
        friend void baz(bar const&) {}
    };
}

int main() {
    foo::bar bar;
    // foo::baz(bar); // ill-formed, no member baz in foo
    baz(bar); // Okay, it *can* be found by ADL
};
```

That is not directly related to your question, but that is how the friend `operator==` is looked up. And that said friend is also not a template itself. When you instantiate `Int<int>`, this "injects" a free `operator==` function - which is, again, not a template - into the namespace `Int` is a member of. When that operator function is looked up (by ADL) for the purposes of doing `x == a`, the compiler will happily consider implicitly converting `a` to `Int<int>`, because we can do implicit conversions to match regular free functions.

And speaking of conversions...

> I wrote simple class and define one copy constructor.

You did not. That is a user-defined constructor taking an `int const&` argument, not an `Int<int> const&` like a copy constructor would take. You defined a converting constructor (because it's not explicit), which is exactly how the compiler can convert `a` to `Int<int>` above.

> If I turn...

In your second version the operator is a template. It's still looked up by ADL. But template argument deduction only considers the **exact** type of the arguments. I.e, both arguments to `operator==` must be directly able to bind to `Int<T> const&` for some `T`. An `int` cannot be bound directly to `Int<int> const&`, it requires a conversion. So it doesn't match the sort of argument the template needs to do template argument deduction. Therefore the template cannot be instantiated, and is not a candidate.

> Does it mean that friend functions allows specific conversions?

No, it's not the friendship. It's the template vs non-template business. You can define an `operator==` without friendship, but it has to be per-instantiation of `Int`:

```
template <class T>
class Int {
public:
    T value;
    Int(const T& value_) : value(value_) {
        ;
    }
};

bool operator==(const Int<int>& f, const Int<int>& s) {
    return f.value == s.value;
}
```

That will make your `main` well-formed too. But as you noticed, it's not very useful having to declare those individually, so many code bases will use the `friend` version to "inject" this free function automatically.

Comment: @YSC - Many thanks! ^_^ Now to figure out what to do with the rest of my life :)

Comment: _Il faut cultiver notre jardin._